# Using different cipher than default

Tags: c#

I need to connect to a server using only one cipher - "ADH-RC4-MD5".
I'm looking for a generic solution which will enable me to check what cipher the server is using (I'm a provisioning server that acts as a client to many other application servers and need to connect and get data - each time it can be a different server).

The flow I had so far was:

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(serverName, port);
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream(), false, null, null,                EncryptionPolicy.RequireEncryption);
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(HostName);
```

I keep on crash in the `AuthenticateAsClient`. The reason is that one AS is working only with the mentioned cipher.

I have verified this is the case with the [SslScan tool](http://code.google.com/p/sslscan-win/).

I have tried to enter this cipher through the policy editor (gpedit.msc in the command line)
but again with no luck.

Basically I'm looking for a way to use this cipher from code dynamically.

I have a working Java code:

```
sslsocket.setNeedClientAuth(true);
String[] list = new String[1];
list[0] = "ADH-RC4-MD5";
sslsocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(list);
```

Any idea of c# equivalent ?

Comment: The way SSL works is that the client sends a list of cipher suites it supports to the server. (This is done by the `AuthenticateAsClient` method.) The server picks the cipher suite that it wants to use. If the list doesn't contain a cipher suite that the server supports, then the SSL connection is aborted.

Comment: thanks for the super quick reply. but what if i know that the server has only one cipher it works with, and i , as a client need to work with it ?

Comment: Then you need to find a client implementation that supports this cipher suite as well. The .NET SslStream cannot be extended with new cipher suites; I believe it just uses whatever Windows provides.

Comment: Does your client actually support `ADH-RC4-MD5`? If it doesn't then that'll be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

---

0) [Recheck](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest) what chipers are supported

1) Check in your server if you have following security update installed (**you need to remove it**)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2898850#AppliesToProducts

If you use win 8.1 it will be disabled, not sure about others. If you want to know why Microsoft encorages you to disable RC4 read [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2013/11/12/security-advisory-2868725-recommendation-to-disable-rc4.aspx).

2)  I am not aware that SslStream allows you to specify allowed ciphersuite(s), however you can use :

- [SecureBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssl.php).
- [chilkat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/) (I maintain few sites that used it)

http://www.example-code.com/csharp/dh_key_exchange.asp

---

Java "ADH-RC4-MD5" should be

```
Supported Protocol = tls (or ssl version 3)
Cipher Algorithm Type = Rc4, 
Hash Algorithm Type = Md5 128 bit, 
Exchange Algorithm Type = DiffieHellman
```